# Halt code at dialog (msgbox()) command in IDE

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio

Title quite much says it all.

In VB6, and in VBA/Access it was possible to hit break key, and jump into debug mode when using the msgbox() command.

Is there a way to do this in vb.net (desktop/winforms) applications?

Often, some code will toss up a dialog box, and it is rather nice then to jump into debug mode as a result of that message box having been displayed.

## Edit

Ok, hitting pause button in most applications work, but in this application, when I hit pause, then I get this:

[image]

## Edit two:

Ok, I have discovered the reason for this behavior. I have the application Frame work box un-checked. The reason for this is I did't want to specify the main application form as startup form, and I desired additional control over what occurs if the main startup form (that I don't specify) is closed. Thus, my main application form is launched via application.Run(my form)

It thus seems that due to starting the main form as a new separate application thread (which is the result of using application.Run(), then you can't use ctrl-break, or more common use/hit the pause button in the IDE to halt the code. Hitting pause will thus display that the application is running a main app thread, which indeed is the case since I use applicaiton.Run() to launch the main form from the classic and traditional Sub Main().

## Edit 3

A way to fix this, and enable the pause key to work is to un-check in tools->debugging the [ ] Enable Just My Code. This will thus allow debug mode of the other "main" application thread.

Comment: Click the pause button in the IDE

Comment: *"Title quite much says it all"*.  I've seen that claim made on numerous occasions and has never been true.

Comment: Hum, ok, in most applications this works. But see my edit in above, when I hit pause (and a standard vb.net msgbox() command is displaying text, then I don't get the IDE + debugger as I normally do. Not sure why this one application behaves differently

Answer (score 1):

Hmm. [CTRL][BREAK] clears the dialog box. However, clicking the pause button in the IDE will do what you want.

Alternatively, select Debug > Break All from the menu.

Comment: I find that works in most applications. However, i added a screen shot as to what happens when I hit pause in this particular application. I am able to place a break point on the msgbox line, but hitting pause results in the above screen show (in my above edit).